# On automorphisms of finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that $a, b\in G$ and $\mid a\mid=\mid b\mid$.
Then does  there exist an automorphism of $G$ such that  $\alpha(a)=(b)$?

Thank you

Comment: Not necessarily. Look at elements of order $2$ in $C_2 \times C_4$.

Comment: Or, more extreme, take $C_2\times S_{3}$. Automorphisms should, in some sense, preserve the relative structure of an element and its relationship with the ambient group. While order is one of the pertinent relationships, it is certainly not all of them. For example, being in the center of the group is another, something failed by my example above.

Comment: Ok. If Let $C_{2}\times C_{4}=<y>\times <x>$,  then there is not an automorphism such that send $x^2$ to  $y$. Is it corroct?

Comment: @DerekHolt. Thank you. You  answer all questions about automorphisms. Your information about automorphisms very wonderful.

Comment: @AlexYoucis but he is just lookibg at abelian groups here!

Comment: @elham: Aaya khodet eide dar morede masale dari?

Comment: It raises the question whether it is possible to classify those finite groups having the property that whenever two elements have the same order, there is an automorphism that carries the one into the other ...

Comment: @B.S: salam. eide khodeh soalo megin ya dar mordeh javabesh?

Comment: @elham: Salam. manzuram jawabe. Man fek konam Derek eideh khube behemun dad ke yek counterexample khube.

Comment: @B.S: baleh mesaleh khubi hast. nazaretoon raje be soale  badei ke naveshtam cheyeh

Comment: @elham: Jaleb bud baram (+1). Waghean jawab gereftan az 2 nafari ke tu soale badit jawab dadan yejur jayeze gereftane inja. Man asheghe rahe hal haye Derek hastam. Ayaa dar barash to net search kardi? Rahe hal haye in mard mano sangkub mikone. Hatman jawabesho ghabul kon. :-)

Comment: @B.S: are Derek holt vaghean yek nabeghast. ay kash ostad rahnamam bood. manam bad joor sheftash shodam fogholladeh javab medeh. hala too in soal ye jabeh kamel ham yeki degeh dadeh nemeedonam kodoomo entekhab konam. mano rahnamaye kon